# Where to dispose instance of non modal form

Tags: vb.net

It is clear with modal forms...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim f As New myForm
    f.ShowDialog(Me)
    f.Dispose
End Sub
```

But what to do with non modal forms?
Where to dispose it?

```
    Dim f As New myForm
    f.Show(Me)
    f.Dispose
```

This will close newly created form immediately so f.Dispose shouldn't stay here.
If I put that in _FormClosing handler will be nice but not enough since we can have few instances of that form running.

1) So, where and how to dispose non modal forms opened like in second example?
2) Is here any event to know that our child form closes?

Comment: 1) In the first, each instance of f will go out of scope when the code exits the click event and .NET will clean it up when it gets around to it.  Second case MIGHt be the same, depending on where that code exists 2) see Form_closed, form_closing events.

Comment: Hi Plutonix, In Form_Closing we can't catch event where child form closes, only when Me closes! I know, I can raise that event from child but I ask if there is automatic way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to call `Dispose` on a modeless form, because the resources of the form are cleaned up for automatically, except for the following two conditions:

1. it is part of a multiple-document interface (MDI) application, and the form is not visible
2. you have displayed the form using `ShowDialog`

Your scenario does not fall into either of the above two conditions, so you do not need to worry about where to put a manual `.Dispose()` call, because it is not needed.

> Read [Form.Close Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close.aspx) documentation for more information.

Comment: Thanks Karl, sounds logical.